# Responsive grid, floated elements move underneath one another when min-width is reached

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm in the process of creating a responsive site (currently only working on the main content.)

I've created two floated divs with percentage based widths. One contains an image which resizes with the browser resizing. The image has a min-width of 100px.

Can anyone tell me why when put into a mobile sized width it doesn't drop down? How can I make the image stack underneath the text?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d6D7/)

[Live site](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/about.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the: 
`min-width: 100px;` to the aside element instead, then on a small screen it drops to the bottom. Good luck with the design. (Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eddturtle/7d6D7/1/)